how can i transfer normal attribute from a part of the mesh to the whole mesh in geometry nodes?
I have a mesh (the tree branch) which has a base and a vertex group assigned to it. I instanced the mesh on a surface and then i shrink-wrapped the base of the mesh (using the vertex group as a selection) on the surface. Now I want to move the rest of the mesh in the direction of the base normal (before i shrink-wrapped it) in order to have its original form (more or less). I Have multiple instances of the mesh, and so this must work with group id.
I tried separating the base, sampling its normal, averaging in per instance with accumulate field nodes and then using it to set offset the position of the other vertices, but i missed something. because it doesn't work as intended.




I hope someone knows what i did wrong.

You can just set the Shrinkwrap modifiers Wrap Mode to be Target Normal Project, then set the offset to displace it by the amount you want. Pretty sure this is what you're describing, already built-in to the modifier.

It's a bit different, this is a small part of the node tree, the whole nodetree also has parts with distribution and other stuff, that i need all in one place as a geometry nodes modifier

It seems that I stumbled to a solution, even though I'm not sure why it works.(i have a suspicion). Maybe someone might tell me if they know.
This is what i ended up doing.

Before and after

